# Android: Keep old thread running after starting new activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a main menu screen that starts a new processing thread on a button click.

The main menu activity then starts a new activity (which means it goes into OnPause()  OnStop() ), and I would like the processing thread to continue to run. From what I've read, it seems like the processing thread will not be destroyed automatically. Does that mean that the thread will persist across activities until the activity is destroyed or the thread is manually terminated?

If I pass a BlockingQueue used with the thread to the new Activity, will the new activity be able to use the queue (take and put) with the old processing thread?

Thanks!

Comment: I know I've had AsyncTasks and threads continue to make UI calls after the recreation, so I'd say probably it would work.  I'd also say it would be bad design-  the thread should instead be owned by a service if you want it to purposely stay running.

Answer (score 0):

The threads should live on that you had started in one activity.  Good practice when you don't want them to survive is to make sure that they are killed within the onPause() and onStop() lifecycle calls.

If you pass along parameters associated with another activity, they will be retained and as long as your thread is still running then you should be able to add to the queue as you desire.  If you are doing this then you will most likely want to pass along the thread identification as well so that you can manage its life-cycle.  If it is something that will be living on beyond one activity, just make sure that you do stop/kill it eventually when you are finished.